# Get the maximum and mininum value of a period setted by me

Tags: pine-script

My intention is get the min and max value for a period setted for me.

Thank you for helping

```
study(title="Líneas verticales horarias- Aarón", shorttitle="Líneas verticales horarias - Aarón",overlay=true)
AsiaON = time(period, '0300-0900')
bgcolor(AsiaON > 0 ? yellow: na, transp=95)

EuropaON = time(period, '0902-1830')
bgcolor(EuropaON > 0 ? blue: na, transp=95)
// I get satisfactorily to draw the vertical lines for indicating my schedules

// Probably my problem is here
localMin = lowest(AsiaON,1)
localMax = highest(EuropaON, 1)
plotchar(localMin, location=location.belowbar, text=localMin)
plotchar(localMax, location=location.abovebar, text=localMax)
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: `period` - is a variable for used on chart resolution.

Comment: Do you want to find max/min in the range `from-to` or what do you want? Could you explain that more precisely

Comment: @Michel_T. the way I understood this question is: OP wants to get lowest value since Asia session started and highest since Europe session started. The problem I had was finding a way to compare the value returned by `AsiaON = time(period, '0300-0900')` and the timestamp of that candle, all of the `time` functions I found return only the current time so it doesn't work for past candles.

Comment: There's a problem with such sessions they don't work and default timezone is used for the case `time(period, '0300-0900')`.

Comment: @BarisYakut do you have tradingview profile? You are an active members of pine society, so the head of tradingview has offer for you. If you don't mind, could you provide your contacts to get in touch with you.

Comment: Hello @Michel_T. my TV account is: https://www.tradingview.com/u/vitruvius/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in pine-script, as described in the [reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_highest) the `highest()` function expects an integer as its second parameter.

In your case, `EuropaON` and `AsiaON` are both a `series` and cannot be turned into an integer.

Comment: You and @BarisYakut are active members of pine society, so the head of tradingview has offer for you. If you don't mind, they'll contact with you. Is that OK?

Comment: I think, TV's profile for private message will be enough

Comment: @Michel_T. no message still

Comment: Hello. I passed your nicknames to the team in tradingview who look for active members of the Pine community. They are going to contact you and describe what they looking for. The only I can is reminding about you to that team.

Comment: No worries, I was not trying to push.